# How do I remove all internal edges of a converted font to mesh?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

I have converted a font to a mesh and I would like to just have the outline.  I need to delete all the internal edges without going through all the pain like the image below.  The red arrow is a manual delete of one edge. I want all the internal edges gone. Is there a quick solution?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's focus on what you want to achieve and not on how. This means asking the question from different perspectives, one being:

> "How do I get the outlines of the Glyphs as mesh edge-loops, quickly?".

The result is the same.

**As a script**

Run this from the Text Editor with the Font object active and in Object mode.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

def convert_to_mesh_outlines(obj):
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE')
    obj.data.dimensions = '3D'
    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

convert_to_mesh_outlines(obj)
```

**Manually**

If you aren't comfortable with running scripts, the following steps are the manual analog of the above.

- Add your Text
- Convert to Curve  (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in Object mode will give the *Convert to* menu )

  [image]

  Notice the highlighted tab changes from F (font) to two dots with a curve (Curve).

  [image]
- Set to kind 3D (yes makes no sense - but you will get an outline immediately)
  [image]
- then Convert to Mesh

  [image]

Answer (score 6):

You may use ***Limited Dissolve*** option. In *Edit Mode* select the whole mesh (<kbd>A</kbd>), then press <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Limited Dissolve*.
[image]

You may need to remove some remaining edges manually though.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Right-click</kbd> twice on the border to select it, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right-click</kbd> to add subsequent edge loops to the selection, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection, then <kbd>X</kbd>> *Edges* to delete all the interior edges:

[image]

Comment: too much work and likely to miss edges.

Comment: @zeffii I think the gif shows how quick and easy it is.

Comment: In the scenario of only one character, i'd agree. Any more characters and i'd be going for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 3):

1. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Select external edges: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> -> *Select Boundary Loop*
3. Separate selected edges into a new mesh: <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]
[image]
[image]